# Тип поля в базе данных для сообщений пользователей

Tags: mysql, php, sql

Какой тип поля должен быть в БД, куда юзер скидивает сообщение: `VARCHAR(32)` или `text`?

Что лучше?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Зависит от того, собираетесь ли вы как-то ограничивать пользователей в длине их сообщения. Если не собираетесь, тогда можно и `text`.

В любом случае, я бы ставил текст и не заморачивался бы.

PS: однозначно не `VARCHAR(32)`. Вам бы понравилось, чтобы ваши сообщения обрезало до 32 символов? :)

Comment: Добавлю, что `VARCHAR`-у не обязательно быть ограниченным 32мя символами. Можно вполне задать `VARCHAR(151)`. Важно, что ограничение должно иметь место (от 1 до 65,535 байт).

Comment: Солидарен. :)

Answer (score 2):

`VARCHAR(32)` подразумевает текст из максимум 32 символов. `TEXT` - 64kb. Какой вариант для Вашей системы лучше, выбирайте сами.

Answer (score 1):

Смотря как ограничено количество символов для сообщения.